# jQuery events executing code in unexpected order

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm having an issue with some of my code executing in an unexpected order. I have two buttons each with a function bound to the click event. One button is 'cancel' and it makes some display changes. The second button is 'done' which saves changes by writing them to a hidden input field and then triggers the event handler on 'cancel'. This is what my code looks like.

```
/*done link*/
$("#donelink").bind('click', function() { 
    var idvalues = $.map($(".ledgerline input:checkbox:checked"), function(el, i) {
  return $(el).val().toString();
}).join(',');
    $("#my_input").val(idvalues);
    $("#cancellink").triggerHandler('click');
  });

/*cancel link*/
$("#cancellink").bind('click', function() {

  /*some basic css and other property changes*/

    $(".ledgerline input:checkbox:checked").parent().parent().trigger('click');

  });

/* The function bound to this event: 
$(".ledgerline input:checkbox:checked").parent().parent().trigger('click');
*/
function { 
    /* other stuff */
    $(this).find("input:checkbox").remove();
}
```

What I expect to happen is that when I click on the 'done' link it will find values from all the checkboxes and write them to #my_input. And then it will hit the cancel link, removing all the checkboxes. What instead happens is that all the checkboxes are first removed, and then an empty string is written in as the value.

Any help? I don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this. Turns out the problem was that the event handler was being triggered twice by code elsewhere. The code I pasted above actually works fine. *smacks self*

Thanks for helping anyways though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this line

```
$("#cancellink").triggerHandler('click');
```

is not waiting for the `$.map` and subsequent value set to finish before executing. You could introduce a callback function that waits for the value to be set before the continuing.

Could you post a succint demo of the code so far on [**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com) so that we can have a look?

***As a side note***
You cannot rely on the event handlers executing in a specific order, as the order of execution is not guaranteed.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ufepu/edit

Here's a pastebin of what the code roughly looks like. How could I introduce a callback to wait for the map function? It doesn't accept another callback argument.

Comment: thanks - what element is `$(".ledgerline input:checkbox:checked").parent().parent()`? is the markup on jsbin the same as what you have in your page?

Comment: That element is the <tr> element. It has a .toggle() event handler on it.

The markup in jsbin is not the same. It's a simplified version of the part of the code that's not working. I updated the pastebin too.